# where are my font files - in my Rails project I use Bower and Material Design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bower, bootstrap-material-design

Bootstrap-Material-Design by [FezVrasta](https://github.com/FezVrasta) is a very nice module! I only have one tiny itch - and that is pertaining to the fonts addressed in the material.css

I'm on Ruby 2.1.2, Rails 4.1.5, Node 0.10.35 and Bower 1.3.7

I added a .bowerrc with

```
{
  "directory" : "vendor/assets/bower_components"
}
```

then I put `gem "bower-rails", "~> 0.9.2"` in my Gemfile

and then I listed the bower packages in Bowerfile

```
# A sample Bowerfile
# Check out https://github.com/42dev/bower-rails#ruby-dsl-configuration for more options
# asset 'bootstrap'

asset "jquery", "2.1.1"
asset "jquery-ujs", "1.0.1"
asset "sweetalert", "0.2.0"
asset "bootstrap-material-design", "0.2.2"
Then I did my bower install – and everything was perfect!
```

But after cap production deploy I have to go and do on my app servers this:

```
cd public && ln -s /var/www/clock/current/vendor/assets/bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/fonts fonts
```

Or else my browser barfs with

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://irrelevant.domain/fonts/Material-Design-Icons.woff?-g7cqhn
Is there a way around this?
```

It's not like I cannot automate the symbolic linking - it just seems kind'a sticking a band-aid on :)

Answer (score 2):

How much I really wanted to use Bower to manage the client side assets, I reverted to letting Bundler do the heavy lifting :/

There is a 'service' - https://rails-assets.org/ - a kind of 'gem wrapping giftshop' that I've used; and as it turned out to be: will continue to use.

It's sweet and easy and all you have to do is follow the short recipe right on the landing page.

Added this snippet to my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-sweetalert'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery-ujs'
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap-material-design'
end
```

kept my require's in application.js and application.scss and waisted all the bower.json, Bowerfile, vendor/assets/bower_components folder etc

and did one last `bundle install`

Case closed :)